# Why doesn't the vscode-cpptools extension provide intellisense for namespaced declarations inside macro definitions?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-code, macros, namespaces

I am using VS Code. All the following description happens on VS Code env.

I got one header with namespace "Loki" defined which is called "Typelist.h"

I am trying to use a struct inside this namespace defined in this header.

I did:

```cpp
# define LOKI_TYPELIST_1(T1) ::Loki::TypeList<T1, ::Loki::NullType>

# define LOKI_TYPELIST_2(T1, T2) ::Loki::TypeList<T1, LOKI_TYPELIST_1(T2)>
```

Normally, I think it should give me intellisense when I am trying to type ::Loki::[Something from namespace Loki], but it doesn't show me anything.

Even, when I am trying to use LOKI_TYPELIST_1 when I define LOKI_TYPELIST_2, it doesn't work either.

What's going on here? Why doesn't the vscode-cpptools extension provide intellisense for namespaced declarations inside macro definitions?

P.S. I did include "Typelist.h" in my current header.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `#define` for this?

Comment: @NathanPierson I am defining an alias of a typelist

Comment: Sounds like a case for `using`, then.

Comment: @NathanPierson sorry, 'Loki' is already my namespace

Comment: I'm not talking about `using namespace Loki;`, I'm saying `template<class T> using LokiTypeList1 = ::Loki::TypeList<T, ::Loki::NullType>;`. Although if you're already in the `Loki` namespace a bunch of the `Loki`s in that are probably redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the vscode-cpptools doesn't provide intellisense inside macro definitions.

This is actually fairly reasonable. What a macro definition really means when the macro gets used is often highly dependent on context where it is used. After all... isn't one of the main features of macros?

Take for an (unrealistic, toy) example: `#define FOO std::`. Let's say I expect to see identifiers for things declared inside the global `std` namespace when I trigger VS Code to provide suggestions there. Who's to say some lunatic won't redefine what `std` is and then use `FOO`?

Granted, if it were instead `#define FOO ::std::`, our imaginary lunatic is out of luck, but I'd wager this is a case of "*It's too much work to distinguish between what is guaranteeable as known inside a macro body, so let's just not provide intellisense there.*"

Here's more (and probably better) food for thought: How would intellisense know what *is* declared inside the `std` namespace at the point of the macro usage? That would depend on what standard headers have been included and what forward declarations have been made before the point of the macro usage. At one usage site, I might have included `<string>`, and at another, not have included it. Etc. A macro can be used in multiple places. How do you give intellisense for something that can have different valid suggestions depending on where it is used?

Even with such a small example (and there are many varying others), there are already two challenges that make this unduly difficult for the vscode-cpptools extension to provide good suggestions/autocomplete for.

Granted- the vscode-cpptools extension can and will show problem highlighting at/inside the macro if any *usage* of that macro has problems, because it uses compiler diagnostic messages to find the "site" of the problem, and most compilers will report the specific macro line and column where the problem is happening in their diagnostic messages (in addition to the line and column of where the macro is being used).

Comment: random meta note: [I just answered a similar question about CSS variables and colour decorations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196827/11107541)